# how to kill port 80 in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, port

I am trying to kill port in ubuntu so that I can run a website.
I used the following command to kill port 80 in Ubuntu. But, I got message as attached in screenshot. Are there any other commands to do this? If so, please let know. Thank u!

Environment : Ubuntu 17.04

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
kill -9 4469
```

OR

```
fuser -k -n tcp 80
```

the port number is 80

or Use [killport](https://github.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/blob/master/killport) command :

```
wget https://raw.github.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/master/killport
killport 3000
```